# How Send .XML file to a View in MVC3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, web

I have  Photo Gallery File with .XML type.I inserted it into App_Data.How I can send it to View In my MVC3 website.
thanks.

Comment: Send to your view as a download or as apart of your model?

Comment: I do not Know.What is better George?thank you.

Comment: Ha -- I think you need to answer that.  Are you trying to display it in your HTML or prompt the user to download an XML file?

Comment: Hi I just need to display it into my HTML.

Comment: I think you have a photo display component that reads an XML file that contains photo URLs, right?  The App_data directory cannot be read over HTTP. Just stick the file in another folder and link to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make the view strongly typed with Model of type `XDocument`

then from the controller load the file into memory. Parse it using `XDocument.Parse()` and then pass the `XDocument` instance to the view

Comment: Ok I do this and send XDocument to View.But any thing not show in view.this is my code in Controller:   public ActionResult PhotoGallery()
        {
            string path1 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Picture.xml");
            XDocument slides = XDocument.Load(path1);
            return View(slides);

        }

Comment: and in view side: 




@{
    ViewBag.Title = "PhotoGallery";
}
<h2>
    PhotoGallery</h2>
@Html.DisplayForModel();

Comment: Can you please provide structure of your XML and i ll help you to make a model out of it and send it to view

Comment: that is structure:<?xml version="1.0"?>

<coffeecupimagegallery version="5.95">

  <imagegallery

  >
  <imagedisplay

  >
  </imagedisplay>

  <button


  >
  </button>

  <button
   
  >
  </button>

  <button
 
  >
  </button>

<image

></image>

  <thumbnailer
  

  >
  </thumbnailer>

  <catagories
  
<!--content-->
  ></catagories>
</imagegallery>
</coffeecupimagegallery>

Comment: I would suggest making a model from the XDocument object. That is, decide which information you need to display from the XML in the view. If you **really** want to display the XML, you can display the XML in `<pre> </pre>` tags to preserve the formatting.